# Where to find Iron John in Chinese?

Tags: books

Does anyone know if there is a Chinese translation of the book [Iron John written by Robert Bly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012271JDA) and if there is a translation, is there any website where an e-book version could be purchased? Any information on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The Chinese name for the book seems to be 鐵約翰 一本關於男性啟蒙的書, although it seems hard to find.  You can Google this name to find places which sell it, such as [here](https://www.books.com.tw/products/0010051174); I only found traditional simplified Chinese translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in douban 读书 page, there are some 网店 selling it
https://book.douban.com/subject/23857531/

Answer (score 1):

it’s out of print. however, the hong kong public library has this book, i would suggest you find someone borrow one for copying or scanning, or, . . .

https://webcat.hkpl.gov.hk/lib/item?id=chamo:2334580&fromLocationLink=false&theme=WEB

have fun :)